# How do you completely reset monitor configuration (e.g. what used to be dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg)?

Tags: unity, monitor

Using unity 11.04. I have a secondary monitor (actually two, one at home, one at work). The home twin monitor set up works perfect (Viewsonic monitor). At work, I get very buggy behaviour, such as full screen applications 'ghosting' when maximized, and other strange effects. I would like to try and completely reset the monitor configurations (not unity or compiz), before doing anything else. In 10.10 this would be accomplished:

```
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's some user preferences settings, then you can create a new user "temp", login as a "temp" and see if it's ok.

You can also try `xrandr --auto`.

Comment: It's *xrandr --output <your output> --auto*